# DRY Gradle Tasks

Tags: gradle, groovy

Is there any neat, straightforward way to abstract away elements of a task in gradle?

I'm creating a mixed project, which includes some Scala to be compiled to Javascript - which doesn't appear to be possible with Gradle alone. However I end up with several tasks that look like this:

```
task buildScalaJS(type: Exec) {
    workingDir './scalajs'
    commandLine '../sbt', 'fastOptJS'
}

task buildScalaJSLauncher(type: Exec, dependsOn: buildScalaJS) {
    workingDir './scalajs'
    commandLine '../sbt', 'scalaJSLauncher'
}
```

My first thought was to abstract this into a function like:

```
def sbt(String... params) {
    workingDir './scalajs'
    commandLine('../sbt', params)
}
```

However, these properties don't exist outside the scope of the task definition, so this (understandably) results in an error.

---

The only other way that I can conceive is to have a function that generates tasks:

```
def sbtTask(String taskName, String sbtTask = taskName, Map options) {
    Map defaultOptions = [type: Exec]
    task ("${taskName}", (defaultOptions << options)) {
        workingDir './scalajs'
        commandLine '../sbt', sbtTask
    }
}

sbtTask('buildScalaJS', 'fastOptJS')
sbtTask('buildScalaJSLauncher', 'scalaJSLauncher', dependsOn: 'buildScalaJS')
```

However, gradle complains that the method 'sbtTask()' couldn't be found.

---

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first option should work if you add the task as argument to `sbt()`:

```
def sbt(task, String ... params) {
    task.workingDir './scalajs'
    task.commandLine('../sbt', params)
}

task buildScalaJS(type: Exec) {
    sbt delegate, 'fastOptJS'
}

task buildScalaJSLauncher(type: Exec, dependsOn: buildScalaJS) {
    sbt delegate, 'scalaJSLauncher'
}
```

EDIT: I see now that you will probably get a problem with the commandLine method, since the arguments will be passed as (String, String[]). You will need to combine them to one list or array, something like this: `task.commandLine(['../sbt'] + (params as List))`

Your second option should also work, but you have a problem in your function definition and in the task definition. Try changing it to something like this:

```
def sbtTask(Map options = [:], String taskName, String sbtTask) {
    Map defaultOptions = [type: Exec]
    task(defaultOptions + options, taskName) {
        workingDir './scalajs'
        commandLine '../sbt', sbtTask
    }
}

sbtTask 'buildScalaJS', 'fastOptJS'
sbtTask 'buildScalaJSLauncher', 'scalaJSLauncher', dependsOn: 'buildScalaJS'
```

Comment: Also +1 for making me aware of `delegate`! Looks like the the main issue I with the second solution was the ordering of the arguments to the function. I played around with it a bit; am I correct to think that the presence of options precludes other default values? And the options map must be the first argument?

Comment: I originally thought that you could have other defaults even with the option map, but couldn't get it to work when experimenting. And yes, if the options map is the first argument, you can put map entries anywhere in the argument list.

Comment: +1... `delegate` just saved me from having a growing amount of tasks, with repeated definitions, in my gradle file, which is now DRY and way more maintainable